# resolving a Promise inside failure of another promise

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise

I want to resolve a promise which in turn makes an ajax call. The promise should be resolved irrespective of the fact whether the ajax call was successful or not. I tried the following snippet:

```js
new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "nonExistentURL",
    headers: {
      "Content-Language": "en"
    },
    async: true,
    type: "DELETE",
    contentType: "application/json",
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: "json"
  }).done(function(oSuccessData) {
    debugger;
    resolve(oSuccessData);
  }).fail(function(oData) {
    debugger;
    resolve(oData);
  });
}).then(function(oData) {
  debugger;
}).catch(function(err) {
  debugger;
});
```

But, this seems to be entering the catch callback always. Why it is not entering the then callback?

Comment: because jquery promises are broken

Comment: jquery `.done` gets `data, textStatus, jqXHR` as arguments, whereas `.fail` gets `jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown` ... this is what jQuery does best, *inconstancy*

Answer (score 5):

It is actually because of the argument that you are receiving in `fail` callback. It is an XHR then-able promise type object. Since you are resolving the function with a `rejected` promise, it comes to the `catch` block.

You could just wrap the `error` object in another object say `{ err: oData }`, then the `then` callback will get resolved properly.

```js
new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "nonExistentURL",
        headers: {
            "Content-Language": "en"
        },
        async: true,
        type: "DELETE",
        contentType: "application/json",
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: "json"
    }).done(function(oSuccessData) {
        console.log("Done callback: Resolving the promise with Data");
        resolve(oSuccessData);
    }).fail(function(oErr) {
        console.log("Fail callback: Resolving the error");
        resolve({ err: oErr });
    });
}
).then(function(oData) {
   console.log("Then Callback");
}).catch(function(err) {
   console.log("Catch the error");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I would rather just work with the other params instead `jqXHR.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {});` ...

Comment: Of course, you can... I was just giving an example. You can resolve with any object except a `rejected` promise.

Comment: `Resolving the error` - it's not though, is it, it's resolving the jQuery bastardised XHR object; which is passed as the first argument to `fail`, but the last argument to `done`

Comment: So it's a bit like you're doing `resolve(Promise.reject())`, interesting! The first Promise was indeed resolved, but the inner rejected one gets unwrapped before going to the lower `.then` / `.catch`

Comment: @JaromandaX Yeah, we aren't exactly resolving the error. It looks like the yash-bagadia wants the access to error object. However, We can do pretty much anything there. LIke, resolve with some other data like "FAILED", or anything that is not a rejected promise.